# javascript onclick repeat

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a form button with an onclick event that runs a simple javascript function (adds 1 to a value).

I have to click the mouse button each time for this to run, is there any way of making it so if the mouse button is held down it runs it too, but every half a sec?

### CURRENT CODE

```
<script>
  function incrementValue(id) {
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
    value=++; 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
    }
</script>
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="attk">
<input type="text" id="def">

<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue('attk')">
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue('def')">
```

Comment: tip : use radix like `parseInt('watever',10)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following will repeat every 500ms while the button is pressed - and will increment a counter

JavaScript:

```
var intervalId; // keep the ret val from setTimeout()
function mousedownfunc(divid) {
    intervalId = setInterval(runme, 500, divid);
}

function mouseupfunc() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
}

function runme(divid) {
    document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = parseFloat(document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

HTML :

```
<input type="button" onmousedown="mousedownfunc('counter')" value="clickme" onmouseup="mouseupfunc('counter')" /><br/>
<div id="counter">1</div>
```

Working example with counter -> http://jsfiddle.net/73uKk/1/

Comment: In my code I have different counters, each one is assigned an id eg `runme(id)`, could you edit code to show that? thanks

Comment: @user1022585 if you add your current code to your question I will update my answer .... ta

Comment: its working now, just one final little issue, it only updates if i hold it down, not if i click. Would the mouseup function need to be adjusted to do this or could i just add an onclick event to the button too?

Comment: You need to add handling for mouse-leave, for cases the user moves the pointer outside the button and then releases.

Comment: I rewrote your example to give a longer pause before the first increment and to reset when moving the mouse off the element while still holding down the click.  http://jsfiddle.net/73uKk/216/

Answer (score 1):

You can add an onmousedown event(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp) to the button.
Then use setTimeout() function (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

```
<input type="submit" onmousedown="func1">


function func1(){  
  //yourcode;  
setTimeout(func1,500);
}
```

Not sure about the right syntax in setTimout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in JQuery:

```
var myInterval = null,
counter = 0;

            $('#buttonID').mousedown(function(){
                myInterval = setInterval(function(){
                    counter++;
                    // display it on page...
                },500);
            });

            $('#buttonID').mouseup(function(){
                clearInterval(myInterval)
            });
```

Define an interval in mousedown and when the mouse click is release (mouseup) clear that interval. I hope that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can  use Javascript Closure

```
var i = 1;
var callMe = function ()
{
    var called = function(){ var j = i++; alert ('now its:'+j); }
    return called();   
}
setInterval(callMe,500);
```

[`see more`](http://web.archive.org/web/20080209105120/http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies)